# Accessing http session in portlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, portlet

A jsp page saves values in the session using the following code

```
session.setAttribute("UserType", "customer");
```

These values need to be accessed in a jboss portlet. Using the following code to access the variable:

```
        String id = (String) renderRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("LoginId", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    System.out.println("FROM SESSION: " + id);
```

I get null as the output. What do I need to do to access the session variable in the portlet?

Comment: You're setting `UserType` and trying to fetch `LoginId` ? Is that why it's null?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, there's an extra bit of configuration needed in JBoss to enable portlet session and httpsession to intermingle: [Chapter 8. Clustering Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/jbportal/v2.4/reference-guide/en/html/clustering.html#PortalSessionReplication)

Check section : 8.3.1. Portal Session Replication

```
<web-app>
   <description>JBoss Portal</description>
   <!-- Comment/Uncomment to enable portal session replication -->
   <distributable/>
   ...
</web-app>
```

You can also see a discussion on the JBoss Community on the same topic: [PortletSession vs HttpSession](http://community.jboss.org/message/412659)

Comment: It's deprecated version of portal.